# "this" keyword in Object method points to Window

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = 'The Window';
var object = {　　
  name: 'My Object',
  getNameFunc: function(){　　　　
    return function() {　　　　　
      return this.name;　　　
    };　
  }
};

console.log( object.getNameFunc()() );
```

when i tested the code. the result is The Window. but i think `this.name;` should be `My Object`. what's wrong with my thinking.

when i add var before the `name : "My Object",` it show's an error.? why?

Comment: Why do you have another inner anonymous function inside `getNameFunc` ? you can just do `return this.name`;

Comment: i remove the another inner anonymous function inside getNameFunc,but the code can't work. var name = "The Window";
var object = {
　　name : "My Object",
　　getNameFunc : function(){　　　　
　　　　　 return this.name;　　　  
 　};
};
alert(object.getNameFunc());

Comment: check my answer below, I've created a code snippet for you with the way it should be done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` inside a function is the "receiver" it was invoked upon.

That is,

1. **for the construct `x.f()`, `this` inside the function (`f`) will evaluate to the value of `x`**.
2. **for all other cases, `this` will evaluate to `window` inside the invoked function.** (The functions `call`, `apply`, and `bind` can also alter `this`... but that's another story.)

In the posted example the second function (the one with `this.name`) is *not* invoked using the `x.f()` form and so `this` is the `window` object.

The "simple fix" is to use a closure: (The first function *is* invoked in the `x.f()` form and thus `this` is the same as `object`, which is as expected. We capture the value of `this` in the current scope via a closure created with `self` and the returned function.)

```
getNameFunc : function () {
    var self = this
    return function () {
        return self.name
    }
}
```

However, I may consider another design, depending :)

Happy coding.

---

Additional clarification, for comment:

...that is because you are using `circle.getArea()` which is of the form `x.f()`. Thus `this` inside the getArea function evaluates to `circle`.

In the code posted you are invoking *two different functions* in a row. Imagine writing the code like this:

```
var nameFunc = object.getNameFunc()
nameFunc()
```

The first function call is in the form of `x.f()` and thus `this` inside getNameFunc is the evaluation of `object`. However, in the second line, the function (nameFunc) is *not* invoked in the form `x.f()`. Therefore, the `this` inside nameFunc (the function returned from getNameFunc) will evaluate to `window`, as discussed above.

Comment: oh, sorry - I have overlooked your post before I had posted mine.

Comment: @Jan Turoň Don't apologize ;-)

Comment: but why this code: var circle = {
  radius : 9,
  getArea : function()
  {
    return (this.radius * this.radius) * Math.PI;
  }
}; this.radius is 9?

Comment: @zhuanzhthou I have updated the post with an additional explanation for the case.

Comment: pst,i understand some. but when i test this code. var object = {
　　name : "My Object",
　　getNameFunc : function(){　　　　
　　　　　 return this.name;
　　　  };
 　
};
alert(object.getNameFunc()); it shows nothing output. why?

Comment: it doesn't output My Object. why? the above is x.f() form

Comment: @zhuanzhoe That code contains a syntax error and will not run :( -- check the error console, or FireBug, etc. (There should be no `;` after the getNameFunc function). [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xE8q8/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the right context for the method, so the `this` keyword will be what you want it to actually be.
The default is in such a scenario for the `this` keyword is to point to the `window` object, because...this is how the JS engine works.

```js
var name = "The Window";
var object = {
  name : "My Object",
  getNameFunc : function(){
    return function(){
      return this.name;
    }.bind(this); // <-- sets the context of "this" to "object"
  }
};
console.log( object.getNameFunc()() );
```

Comment: where the scope of the  the inner function is the Window object (to make it more confusing ;)

Comment: The "fix" breaks the semantics of `getNameFunc` as now it returns a ... non-function :( (And adds lot of superfluous code.)

Comment: @cysnc "getName<em>Func</em>" :-) If it were just "getName", I'd entirely agree. In any case the above goes a long way to get to `getName/getNameFunc : function () { return this.name }`

Answer (score 2):

```
var myObject = {
    name:'My Object'
};

console.log(myObject.name);
console.log(myObject['name']);
```

There are various other ways to make objects in javascript.

`this` is a hidden argument that is automatically passed from the calling function to the callee. The traditional way is to do:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.name = 'My Object';
}
myObject = new MyObject();

console.log(myObject.name);
```

Nowadays you might just use closures:

```
[**edit**: redacted because not a good method]
```

Nowadays you might just use closures, correctly:

```
function makeObject() {
    var THIS = {};

    THIS.name = 'My Object';
    THIS.sayMyName = function () {
        return THIS.name+" is my name";
    }

    return THIS;
}
```

There are many libraries that support "smarter" ways to make objects as well.

Comment: you last example makes no sense..why would you define 'name' outside as VAR then reference to it by name:name...

Comment: It makes sense ... in an odd fragile sort of way. The `sayMyName` function binds to the closure'd `name` variable, but yet direct access to `name` is allowed via the `name` property ... it's fragile because `timmy.name = "TIMMMEH!"; timmy.sayMyName()` can lead to some very interesting results. That being said, with the *new* getters/setters in Ed. 5, something like this can be implemented entirely with closures... (before it would have required getName/setName or similar)

Answer (score 1):

As the others have written, you need to target `this`. I believe this piece of code will help you to understand how `this` in javascript works

```
var name = "The Window";
var object = {
  name : "My Object",
  getNameFunc : function(){
    that = this; // targeting this
    return function() {
      return that.name;
    };
  }
};
alert(object.getNameFunc()()); // it is My Object now
```

Comment: Make sure to use `var that = this`. Without the `var` the variable `that` will be a *global property* (really `window.that`) and not a variable bound in a closure :( This won't matter here, but it will lead to very subtle bugs in all but the most trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
var object = {
　　name : "My Object",
　　getNameFunc : function(){
　　　　return (function(){
　　　　　 return this.name;
　　　  }).bind(this);
 　}
};
```

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), use the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for browser support

Comment: beautiful code, I like it. didn't know about this bind thing, is there a name for this type of method?

Comment: BUT it gave me a brilliant idea. `return　(function(){ return this.name }).apply(this);`

Comment: @vsync it should work on FF4. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/2Pe5j/) it works for me.

Comment: @vsync that `.apply` snippet is the same as `return this.name`

Comment: well it doesn't I don't know why. it just returns the anonymous function itself

Comment: you have to call `object.getNamefunc()()` it returns a function that you have to call.

Comment: assign it like so: `return (function(){ return this.name }).bind(this)();`

Comment: @vsync no don't execute the bind :(. that's the same as `return this.name`

Comment: I think it's not pretty to always remember in your code that in order to call the `getNameFunc` you have to do `()()`...this is prone to errors in a large code where you might forget things like that

Comment: @vsync ._. then just do `return this.name`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you have declared your function.

The important point we need to remember while placing function inside a method is to use arrow function (if our function block is going to have a **this** keyword).

Instead of declaring a new variable and assigning this keyword to the variable, we can easily solve this problem using Arrow Functions.

Just convert the normal function into arrow function and boom it will work.

```
var name = 'The Window';
var object = {　　
  name: 'My Object',
  getNameFunc: function(){　　　　
    return () => {　　　　　
      return this.name;　　　
    };　
  }
};

console.log( object.getNameFunc()() );
```

This works because arrow functions are always lexically binded and not dynamically binded like any other functions.