# Still confusing about Closure in Javascript with example

Tags: javascript

I'm a fresh hand in Javascript. Now I'm trying to understand Closure. In most common case it's easy to understand. But there are still something very confusing. **This might be a question about `this` in javascript. I'm not sure about it.**

Here are 3 examples:
1:

```js
var name = "The Window";

var object = {
  name: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

console.log(object.getNameFunc()); // 'My Object'
```

2:

```js
var name = "The Window";

var object = {
  name: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function() {
    return function() {
      return this.name;
    };
  }
};

console.log(object.getNameFunc()()); // 'The Window'
```

and last one:

```js
var name = "The Window";

var object = {
  name: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function() {
    var that = this;
    return function() {
      return that.name;
    };
  }
};

console.log(object.getNameFunc()()); // 'My Object'
```

First one is very easy to understand. But why second one return `The Window` and third one return `My Object`.

Comment: duplicate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Comment: 2 and 3 don't run at all, you have an invalid `;` after the `getNameFunc` function.

Comment: When I fix that, 2 and 3 print the function definitions, not a string. Can you fix the snippets to show the actual code?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, fixed it

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is an object, in 3 when you use 'that' you are saving the context of 'this' when you delve into another function 'this' changes.

Comment: @NavidYousefzai Actually I can understand cases in that question. They are all like the first one. But nothing like second or third one. This might be about `this` I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Did you look on this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476521/this-keyword-in-object-method-points-to-window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a special keyword, not an ordinary variable, and it's not saved in closures. So in the 2nd version, the inner closure does not use the value of `this` that was received by `getNameFunc()`, it defaults to the global value, which is the `Window` object.

The 3rd version works because `that` is a normal variable, so it's preserved in the closure.

You can either bind the function like this:

```js
var name = "The Window";

var object = {
  name: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function() {
    return (function() {
      return this.name;
    }).bind(this);
  }
};

console.log(object.getNameFunc()()); // 'The Window'
```

or use an arrow function:

```js
var name = "The Window";

var object = {
  name: "My Object",
  getNameFunc: function() {
    return () => this.name;
  }
};

console.log(object.getNameFunc()()); // 'The Window'
```

For more information, see [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: So in 2nd `object.getNameFunc()` return `function() { return this.name }`. It equals to define a function in window. So it get `The Window`. Am I right?